# Let Bindings Type Inference

Tags: .net, types, f#

I have the following code in F#:

```
let value = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("type")
if value <> null then 
   //we know type is not null
```

Here I do not specify a type for `value`. However, since F# is a statically typed language, the compiler must deduce an exact type for each construct during compilation. In this particular case, value is either `null` or a `String`. How does the compiler handle this? What is the type assigned to value at runtime?

Comment: There is no `null` type in .net, it inhabits all reference types including `string`. So the type of `value` is `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the type of `value` will be whatever the `StringForKey` function returns. If that function is defined to return a `string`, then the value is `string`.

It is possible for a function to be polymorphic in return type, e.g.:

```
let f (x: string) : 'r = ...
```

Here, the return type of `f` will be some type `'r` that is chosen by the caller. In such case, the type of `value` will be determined from other operations you do with it, for example:

```
let value = f "abc"
let value2 = value + 2
```

Here, since `value` is used as an operand of `(+)`, where the second operand is an integer number (type `int`), then `value` itself must also be an `int`, and therefore, the generic argument of `f` must also have been `int`.

In a case where the type of `value` cannot be thus determined, but it affects the type of the enclosing function, the enclosing function will be made generic:

```
let g() = 
    let value = f "abc"
    value
```

Here, the function `g` itself will gain a generic parameter and will have type `unit -> 'r`, and inside the function, `value` will have type `'r`.

In a case where the type cannot be thus "promoted" to the enclosing function, a compile-time warning will be generated, and the type will be fixed to `obj` - the supertype of all types. To avoid this, you can provide a type annotation to resolve the ambiguity.